# create multiple tables in a single query

Tags: sql

Is it possible to output several tables from a single query? 
The code below is incorrect, just to show the main idea:

```
create table A, B, C AS
(select * from main_table where x = 5) AS A
(select * from main_table where x = 8) AS B
(select * from main_table where x = 2) AS C
```

Comment: Use 3 separate `create table` commands.

Comment: should I assume from your suggestion that it is not possible ?

Comment: If you are using Oracle, You must refer https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general001.htm#ADMIN11523

Comment: i am using teradata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a single SQL statement, then, no. You can surely do it one after the other in a single script, that can run in 1 go.

Answer (score 1):

As @gordon suggested in the comments, you could do it all in one script:

```
CREATE TABLE a AS (SELECT * FROM main_table WHERE x = 5);
CREATE TABLE b AS (SELECT * FROM main_table WHERE x = 8);
CREATE TABLE c AS (SELECT * FROM main_table WHERE x = 2);
```